# Graphics engines during the sixth console generation

Tags: 3d

From my understanding game developers used mostly proprietary, in-house graphics engines during the sixth console generation (Xbox, PS2, GC, DC) on a game to game basis. Why didn't standard engines like Unreal (for consoles), Unity etc. emerge earlier?
Wasn't it very inefficient to develop a new engine just for one (or probably a few) games?

Bonus question: Are there any good ressources on graphics development during that time? I'm especially interested in articles about the effort needed to develop an engine for any of the mentioned consoles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renderware was common on the PS2.

[List of PS2 Renderware titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RenderWare_games)

I would guess because these platforms were proprietary and none-standard from a graphics and resources POV that it would be a bigger effort to port Unreal along with all their existing content creation tools.